# numpy search by type element and change it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array `a` and 2d array `b`. I need to calculate `c =a/b`,
so there is some `inf` or `NaN` objects. How can I check it with numpy and set them to `np.nan`?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
b=np.asarray([[1,2,0,4,5],[1,2,0,4,5],[1,2,0,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
c=a/b
b=np.where(isinstance(c, float),np.nan,c)
```

Comment: `c[c==np.inf] = np.nan`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, correct me if I am wrong, You are referring the inf objects in c i.e after calculating c = a/b.

Following is the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore') #To avoid RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide after removing the cwd from sys.path.
a=np.asarray([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
b=np.asarray([[1,2,0,4,5],[1,2,0,4,5],[1,2,0,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
c=a/b
print(c)

[[ 1.  1. inf  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1. inf  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1. inf  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]

c[np.isinf(c)] = np.nan #Finds inf object and replace with nan.
print(c)

[[ 1.  1. nan  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1. nan  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1. nan  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Hope it helps!

Attached the jupyter notebook screenshot for reference:

[image]